# Is it safe to store log files in ContentRoot directory

Tags: asp.net-core

My Asp.net Core 3.1 application store sensitive files in the ContentRoot directory. Is it safe to do so? Where should log files be stored? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not allowing [Static file serving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1) then you are more or less safe from [directory traversal attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack), [Owasp link](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal). (`Path.Combine` can also be harmful)

The best practise is to store your logs on a separate drive, because if they start to grow insanely then it won't hit your application performance directly. On the other hand your write/flush functions might throw `IOException` with the similar error message: " There is not enough space on the disk." so you should handle them.

Depending on how your logs are collected (push or pull based) you can prevent data flooding. But that's out of the scope of the question. :)

Comment: Hi Peter, I do use static files. Thanks for the links.